# Custom work for Wordpress CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

Is there anyone who can help me with some customised data for my CiviCRM (for wordpress)

1. I need the fields from New Contact to be replaced with my own.

   - It will be included a start date.
2. I need to have reminder with 30 days before expiring the "start date" - custom email template

   - I need to have reminder with 7 days before expiring the "start date" - custom email template
   - I need to have reminder with 1 day before expiring the "start date" - custom email template
3. The dashboard should show only some columns that I choose, not everything - with sorting, searching and filtering.

That's it.
I will pay, just tell me who can do that for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can find paid CiviCRM consultants on this list [here](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).

With that said - much of what you'd like to do should be something you can do yourself, you may just need training.  I would recommend finding a consultant who will train you to set these things up together.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I already contacted 3-4 guys from there, and no one is available :)
They give me this page, to ask for help...So I am waiting an offer :D

Comment: Hey Jon
When you have time, can you please give me some step by step how should I do what I need?
Or, if I give you username and pass, can you please just make one, and I will check what you did, and I will replicate it?
Thank you